# How can I add a column indicating clusters on my original df? Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have clustered pitchers in baseball based off of averages of advanced metrics. I am working with statcast data, so every data point is a pitch thrown as follows:

| pitcher_name | batter_name | spin_rate | release_speed | release_position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| derek | alan | 2000 | 90 | -1.05 |
| derek | alan | 2100 | 88 | -1.03 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

To cluster pitchers, I standardized and used kmeans from sklearn to cluster based on averages of advanced metrics. The new df contains no duplicate names of pitchers, just a map from each pitcher to their respective clusters.

What I want to do is add the cluster number of each pitcher to the original dataframe. That way I can calculate batting averages based on subsets.

I was hoping to get something like this:

| pitcher_name | batter_name | spin_rate | release_speed | release_position | cluster |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| derek | alan | 2000 | 90 | -1.05 | 0 |
| derek | phil | 2100 | 88 | -1.03 | 0 |
| stevie | alan | 1800 | 94 | 1.09 | 2 |

Note that I have already created a cluster map, such that for any given cluster, I can find the players in that group.

Does anybody have any advice?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a dataframe that has the mapping between the pitcher and their cluster you can simply join this dataframe to your original dataframe using [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
original_df.merge(cluster_mapping, on="pitcher_name")
```

Comment: This worked beautifully thank you! I would upvote but I just made an account so I have no karma.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something like this:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = n_clusters).fit(X)
```

You just need:

```
df.loc[:,"cluster"] = kmeans.labels_
```